# Accessing form field array

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following form:

```
<form name="quickAdd" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return quickAddProcess(this);">
    <input type="hidden" name="quickAddFields[module]" value="Products">
    <input type="text" name="quickAddFields[name]">
    <input type="checkbox" name="quickAddFields[toList]">
</form>
```

When trying to access them from Chrome's console, I cannot manage to do it:
`document.quickAdd.quickAddFields == undefined;`
`document.quickAdd.quickAddFields.module == TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined`

But, PHP retrieves the array perfectly.

How do I access these fields with plain JavaScript?

#### update:

Oh, `document.getElementsByName('quickAddFields[module]);` works. Why can't I access it through `Form` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
document.quickAdd['quickAddFields[module]']
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/yWm3L/

The name of the form element contains `[` and `]` characters. Therefore, you cannot use the dot-notation (e.g. `foo.bar`). Instead you have to use the subscript-notation (e.g. `foo['bar']`).